# CSS line-height is not being applied

Tags: css

I have an HTML Paragraph element with some inline styles

```
font-style: normal;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
```

These are the values I see in the computed css values in the dev tools.

```
font-size 12px
font-style normal
font-weight 400
height 14.4px
line-height 15px
```

[image]

The problem is that the line-height and font-size styles are not beeing applied. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: the computed value are showing exactly the value you set so they are applied

Comment: yes, but when I use the "Inspect Tool" in the element, I can't see the value of the line-height

Comment: how you want to *see* line-height?

Comment: I would like to see the 15px beeing used and reflecting in the element height, for example,

1 line of text: 15px
2 lines of text: 30px
3 lines of text: 45px

Comment: line-height doesn't automatically define the height. Share your full code and we can explain you why. More factors are considered to define the height

Comment: I created a CodePen https://codepen.io/thiagonunesbatista/pen/gOWmvbY

Comment: no, you need to add the code to your question